# Is it possible to use Cordova plugin for native application WKWebView?

Tags: cordova, webrtc, wkwebview

I'm working on native IOS application, but the part of the content in the WKWebView. And now I'm trying to make work webrtc in the WKWebView. I've found a plugin in Cordova which makes a bridge between native WebRTC and js, but how can I use it in my native application and apply it to my WKWebView?

Here is this plugin - https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc

Comment: Hi how did you achieve this? I have the same problem wkWebView is not supporting WebRTC

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a hybrid application to do so.

Please follow the below link in order to do so.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html

All the best. Feel free to ping me for further issues.

Comment: Can I make a hybrid Cordova application with a remote url?

Comment: what do you mean by remote URL? Please specify your requirement completely, then I can help.

Comment: I mean to load in cordova window some external url like "google.com"

Comment: ya, it is very much possible. When you set up a hybrid app, the default HTML file will be index.html. In that file, you can code to further load any external URL.

Comment: @codeGeek is it possible to implement this functionality in my native iOS app??

Comment: I've just implemented WebRTC natively, so when the call started I show native View above the WKWebView and use this implementation of WebRTC on IOS:
https://github.com/Anakros/WebRTC